# Trying to setup react but npm start command giving me ENOENT error

Tags: npm

> ```
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
> npm ERR! syscall open
> npm ERR! path C:\Work\React_App\package.json
> npm ERR! errno -4058
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Work\React_App\package.json'
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> C:\Work\React_App>npm -v
> 6.14.5
>
> C:\Work\React_App>node -v
> v12.16.1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it looks like NPM is using your .gitignore as a base for the .npmignore file, and thus ignores /lib. If you add a blank .npmignore file into the root of your application, everything should work.

[edit] - more info on this behaviour here: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package